# QGIS algorithm parameter: <ParameterString>

Tags: qgis, pyqgis

I have been working with the algorithm `gdalogr:warpreproject`and have failed several times in the parameter in the title. Now, the problem is solved. It was about the EXTRA parameter. I read 3 books, and I know the explanation, but what I do not understand is the fact that it accepts an empty string. Furthermore, it ONLY accepts that empty string. My code is:

```
reproj = processing.runalg("gdalogr:warpreproject", raster, "EPSG: 25830", "EPSG:4326", '0', 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 1, 1, False, 1, False, "", "G:\\pyQGIS\\MIRAR_COMP\\nuevo.tif")
```

Can anybody explain how does this parameter work?

Comment: Related post: [QGIS Processing - Additional Creation Parameter for GdalWarp](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/111252/qgis-processing-additional-creation-parameter-for-gdalwarp).

Answer (score 0):

It will allow specifying parameters which are supported by OGR but not (yet) by processing to allow full control for not yet supported features.

GDAL(OGR) is a separate library and application. It is often shipped bundled with QGIS but developed independently.

Its tools accept a range of parameters which are normally mapped to processing parameters. But due to the different development cycles, there are sometimes parameters that have not yet been mapped. These parameters can be specified with the EXTRA parameter.

For a list of supported parameters have a look at http://www.gdal.org/gdalwarp.html. And then compare this list to the one which is supported by your local processing installation.